# $f$ not separable $\iff$ there exists a $g$ such that $f = g(x^p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF [Irreducible polynomial over a field $k$ with $char\ k = p > 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1261159/943349)**

> Let $K$ be a field and $\operatorname{char}(K) = p > 0$. Let $f \in K[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Show that $f$ is not separable iff there exists a $g \in K[X]$ with $f = g(x^p)$.

I was able to show the $\impliedby$ direction pretty easily by using the fact that $f$ separable $\iff$ $f' \neq 0$ (assuming f is irreducible).

I looked on the internetz and found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1261159/943349), yet I do not quite understand how they conclude that such a $g$ exists, please elaborate on that part in your answer (fwiw the link in the question does not work for me; 403).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about the separability requirement.  If $n=0$ then $g_0=f$ satisfies $g_0(x^{p^0}) = f(x)$ and by considering degrees, there is a maximum $n$ such that some $g_n \in K[X]$ exists such that $g_n(x^{p^n}) = f$ (This argument only assumes $f$ isn't constant).  We define $g$ to be this $g_n$ with maximum $n$.

In this way, the existence of $g$ isn't really of concern, just its being seperable.